# Barchart x & y -axis tooltip overlaps with title

Tags: primefaces

I am using Primefaces 4.0.Problem is with the barchart, the bar touches the canvas border and when i hover mouse over the bar then x-y axis label overlapes the title of the bar chart.My Barchart values ranges from 0 to 40.

[image: Primeface bar chart]

My barchart code is as follows

```
 <p:barChart 
        value="#{chartBean.chart}" title="#{chartBean.title}"
        style="height:140px;width:320px" 
        barMargin="18" barPadding="10" animate="true">
  </p:barChart>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **min** attribute.Hope it solves your problem.

```
 <p:barChart 
        value="#{chartBean.chart}" title="#{chartBean.title}"
        style="height:140px;width:320px" 
        barMargin="18" min="0" barPadding="10" animate="true">
 </p:barChart>
```